# How to improve performance on table that only have index on a varchar(5000) field and it size is 7.5GB?

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have 2 tables similar in structre let's call them table A and B

in table A I only have an index on a field called token of varchar(5000) the total size of this table is 7.5GB.
in table B I only have an index on a filed called key of varchar(36) the total size of this table is 351 MB.

in table A when I run a query

```
select count(*) FROM A a where a.name like 'my name';
```

this query takes around 17s to execute

in table B hen I run a query

```
select count(*) FROM B b where b.lastName like 'my name';
```

this query takes around 0.5s to execute

does the size of table A affecting my query?

does adding indexes for other fields like name in A will improve the performance?

or does the index on Varchar(5000) in table A field is the one causing issues?

Comment: Are you sure you don't use `%my name%` in your like? Are your `name` and `lastName` column indexed or not?

Comment: no I query for specific values I dont use the wild cards

Comment: Okay so, like the answer says, you just have to index name and lastName to increase your DB performance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the size of the tables causes the difference in performance between the queries because you don't use any of the existing indexes when querying the `name` and `lastName` columns, which causes a full table scan.

If you will create a new index on the `name` column it will dramatically improve the performance because then it will use this index.

Comment: Let me add that the storage involved seems pretty slow.